# How to sort an NSArray using different sort functions

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`, in which I create an `NSArray` of `NSStrings` from one of the elements in the `NSDictionary`.

I am then trying to sort both, but I am getting slightly different results from both sorts.

the `NSDictionary` is simple

```
NAME
Number
```

I am the first `NSArray` and creating a new `NSArray` using the **NAME** element of the dictionary.

I am then sorting the first array like this

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"NAME" ascending:YES]; // 1
sortedByNameArray = [dataArrayOfDictionaries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

I then take the second array, which is exactly the same order before the first is sorted and sort it like this

```
// sorts nicknames
newSortedArray = [nameOnlyArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

And although both arrays are sorted alphabetically `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` seems to do a good job of sorting where as my other `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` only seems to sort using the first letter so its not truly sorted.

I would like some help applying `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` to the `NSArray` of Dictionaries.. but I am not sure how to do this considering you have to access the NAME element of each `NSDictionary` inside the first `NSArray`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare in the first case, use

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"NAME" 
    ascending:YES 
    selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```